# Does an Excluded Directory in Windows 10 Defender Also Include the Sub Directories?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I know [how to exclude a file or folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/64495205-6ddb-4da1-8534-1aeaf64c0af8/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-defender) (directory) from Windows Defender in Windows 10.  What I'm not sure about is whether this exclusion applies to all sub directories within that directory?  It seems to me like it should, but I couldn't find anything from a quick Google search that revealed the answer.  Thanks!

**Update**
I'm hoping to get some actual documentation for this.  I agree that it seems like it should, but I couldn't find definitive source for the answer, other than my own assumptions.

Comment: Yes;  It does indeed include directories and files within an excluded directory.

Comment: Kinda-sorta. It appears that that when transferring files from a local drive to a remote drive, with both sources excluded, `Antimaleware Service Executable` spikes hard in little bursts slowing down the copy-operations. I'm guessing each file is being assessed as to whether or not it's in a white-listed location, so it's not scanning them but it's still slowing stuff down, just not as much as it would if it performed a scan on each file.

Comment: The funny thing is, if they updated Windows Defender to use WinRT for that location-check, they'd only ever need to check the top-level directory node (not the files inside them) one time instead of N times and then use the WinRT data structure to iterate through all the items in that node, where N represents the amount of filesystem objects. *sigh*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, excluding a directory in Defender will also exclude all files and subdirectories recursively.

Comment: Any chance you've got a source? Experience counts :)

Comment: This is one of my personal SO/SU accounts, but I work for Microsoft on the Windows Defender team.

Comment: Well, I suppose that's good enough ;)    Reminds me of Mark Adler's comment from his answer about the code he wrote http://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054/1380

Comment: @RaptorFactor does the exclusions apply to real time scanning? Documentation says so, but some people disagree.

Comment: @NickDeVore [Here you go](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26): "A folder exclusion will apply to all subfolders within the folder as well."

Comment: I added the folder of all Android/Java projects to exclusion but Idea/Android studio still detects that Window Defender doesn't exclude it?

Answer (score 19):

sub directories are excluded, too. documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: That should be the accepted answer considering the reference. :) " A folder exclusion will apply to all subfolders within the folder as well."

Answer (score 12):

Yes, subdirectories are covered by exclusions. HOWEVER, exclusions only apply to scanning, not to Real-Time Protection. If Real-Time Protection is active, every loaded executable is scanned, even those loaded from an excluded directory.

Comment: +1 to mention that it does no apply to real time protection scanning.

Comment: The documentation says differently: "The exclusions apply to scheduled scans, on-demand scans, and always-on real-time protection and monitoring. Exclusions for process-opened files only apply to real-time protection."
Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-exclusions-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: In my actual experience at least one excluded directory did get scanned. I know because one of the files got flagged.

Comment: Oh, so that's what's going on. Every time I compile our application, Windows Defender sits at 100% CPU usage for an hour afterwards, even without moving bytes.  I added everything in Exclusions, now I know why.

Comment: Is there any way to add an exclusion to real time scanning?

Comment: From testing with EICAR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) this answer is inaccurate; Defender's real-time protection rightly ignores excluded folders, and indeed subfolders, per @weberjn's answer.

As for RashaMatt's experience, it's possible that a process was running that was flagged by Defender, that happened to exist in an excluded folder. Note that processes as well as paths can be excluded, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-process-opened-file-exclusions-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide